# TFS goes hang while taking latest file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

We have TFS 2010 on our server. We have one large project around 900 MB because of many images and other resource file. Now when someone is open it in local visual studio and try to get latest files than VS 2010 goes not responding mode and close with error.

Is any maintainance of TFS required for run project smoothly. this issues arise within past 2 month only.

Comment: We had similar issues because the proxy server was limiting the maximum number of requests from one client. And similar issues where the virus scanner started blocking connections temporarily. There's a few extensions that can cause issues as well.